Speed and mass of a rock needed to obliterate a tank
Suppose we have a weapon with the capability to pick up a rock with a variable amount of mass and then accelerate it at a chosen speed. The users of the weapon encounter a weapon in the form of a tank. They decide to use the weapon to destroy the tank. However, the weapon has a limited amount of power so slower rock acceleration is preferable. So what is the optimal speed and mass of a rock in order for it to destroy a tank?

The tank is the standard M1 Abrams.
The rock has a maximum mass of 500 kg.
As I said before the rock is preferable to have slower speeds due to energy costs.
The rock is made of granite and as such is hard, and resilient.
I am defining destroy as making the tank unusable for combat similar to when an anti tank missile is shot into the tank. The tanks Armour  has to be penetrated into the center of the tank.


What kind of rock? Some are very hard, some will fall apart under your fingernail.

Here are some questions you might want to answer for the sakes of those answering:

What properties does this rock have? Is it soft and brittle (e.g. chalk) or hard and resilient (e.g. granite)? Should we just treat it as indestructible for the purposes of this question?
What would you consider "unusable for combat"? Broken tracks? Immobilized? Penetrated armor? Incapacitated crew? If incapacitated crew, how many would be enough?
Other than that, your question is pretty solid.


@Escapeddentalpatient. Is that better?

Yes, thanks. I'm still slightly concerned that some might view it as not worldbuilding and vote to close, but here's hoping...

What angle will it hit the Abrams from? A rock coming down from above will be able to do much more damage than one coming from the front or rear, and one hitting the side will be somewhere in between.

Dropping half a ton from above on a tank easily bends the canon, thus rendering the tank useless... but does not penetrate the armour. Would that suffice?

I don't see how it could penetrate the armor, no matter how fast it comes. What it can do is squish the tank, if it hits it with sufficient kinetic energy. And even more easily it can overturn it. And even more easily it can render the cannon inoperable.

This is too vague. Pick one mass and stick with it. There is a minimum mass below which if it hit hard enough to cause nuclear fusion it still wouldn't damage the tank or its occupants in a meaningful way and you've said your energy is limited. If you're looking for help designing the weapon (which we're happy to do!) then ask two questions: maximum mass and minimum mass.

Worth noting that 500kg of granite is not a particularly big rock because rock in general and granite in particular is heavy.  It'd be a cube about 60cm to a side, or a strangely-wide PC tower, for scale.

Do you want any reasonably aimed shot with the rock to destroy the tank or is it allowed to do some extremely low probability accuracy shots like shooting the rock into the cannon?

Some frame-ish challenges incoming
So there are 3 different ways to 'kill' a Tank.

Mobility Kill
Firepower Kill
Catastrophic Kill

The first is pretty simple - you stop the Tank from moving. Now - granted it can still fire its cannon, but if it is stationary it is more vulnerable to other things on the battlefield and it cant advance and flank you.
Yes, the US Army in the 1940s after the war experimented with the effectiveness of the Anti-Tank Rock
However - from your description, it sounds like you are wanting a Catastrophic Kill - you know the sort we see on LiveLeak videos where the Turret goes flying off the tank and it dramatically (and permanently) changes shape.
Using a half-tonne rock to do this - I do not think is plausible by itself - The Rock is not going to be hard enough to penetrate the Armour of the Tank. It could certain dent the armour - as a comment pointed out - bending the Gun Tube is a very real possibility - but penetrating the armour - that is gonna be tricky.
That said - running the Maths, the Muzzle velocity of an M1 Abrams tank round is around 12 MJ, and with your half-tonne rock, to get the same amount of energy is only 220 m/s - so if you can get it up to that speeds - when I say Dent the Armour - I mean really mess it up, possibly breaking things like the Turret ring and disabling the tank in such a way it can't fight back (a Firepower kill).
However... with a bit of luck, there may be a way to create a Catastrophic Kill
Obstructing the Barrel! A rock with a size less than 120mm in diameter (and remember the Abrams has a Smoothbore cannon) - If it was sufficiently accurate, getting the Rock wedged down the tube, letting the cannon fire and then rupturing the gun tube (and causing a big explosion) - not quite a fully catastrophic kill (the crew probably survive) - but it is the most realistic way of using a Rock to Kill a Tank.

This video might help with your answer! Animation of a stone hurled by the Tsar Cannon at an M1 tank.

@elemtilas - though in the video, the stone is portrayed as invulnerable and inelastic.

@elemtilas - I forgot about that channel - good find

the SHAPE of the rock matters a lot, because we need to minimize the loss of kinetic energy due to air resistance.
Assuming the rock is perfect for the job: a column of granite with a sharp "arrowhead" that is slightly heavier than the rest of the column to stabilize it, you could let it freefall from orbit and hit the tank dead on from the top.
Assuming the rock-arrow is 500kg, letting it achieve around 8.8 Mach would do nicely if your goal is to obliterate a tank, not just destroy it.

Death By Spalling
Many modern anti-tank shells are not designed to go through the armor, instead, they fire a delayed detonation plastic explosive the sends a shockwave through the armor to cause the backside to fragment killing/destroying everything on the other side.  A large rock could kill a tank by a similar mechanic as long as it has enough total kinetic energy and is moving fast enough to exceed the tank's ballistic limit, which for armor grade steel is about 240m/s.
A 120mm HESH shell is an anti-tank shell that contains about 3800cc of plastic explosives which would be about 42MJ of C4. IIRC: these HESH rounds are about 70% efficient meaning that you are looking at an effect similar to a 30MJ kinetic impact.
This means that a 500kg projectile moving at 245m/s will be just barely over the ballistic limit and have about the same spalling capabilities of a 120mm HESH anti-tank shell.  So your rock won't "penetrate" the armor per say, but it will give you a catastrophic kill.
What About Spaced Armor and Spall Liners?
An M1A1 can generally shrug off a 120mm HESH round to the face just fine.  This is because it uses spaced armor and spall liners to contain any spalling effects; however, attacks from above are a different story.  The armor on top of the M1A1 is much thinner than and lacks the spacing features of the frontal armor meaning that something as weak as an RPG-7 can penetrate it.
Because this is a 245m/s thrown rock, and not a 1,400 m/s tank shell, it will not fly in a particularly straight line.  M1A1s can typically spot and kill light to moderately armored targets at ranges of 3-5km; so, we have to assume you can return fire at these ranges, or else you will end up dead on arrival like all the Soviet tanks in Desert Storm that only had a 2km effective range.  At these ranges and speeds, a tank shell will have less than a 1 degree downward angle on impact meaning there is no getting around the front armor, but for your slower rock thrower: at these ranges you will hit the tank at an angle of at least 15 degrees causing a top-down kill around the thick frontal armor.  From this angle, the armor on an M1A1 Abrams is only about 1 inch thick; so, not only will you spall the whole crew to death, but you will probably cave the whole top of the tank in.


That won't work with an M1, they (reputedly) have composite armour with different materials to absorb shockwaves, plus spall liners.

@MontyWild Spall liners are just a last line of defense, and only effective to a point.  The real spall defensiveness of the M1 is in its spaced armor.  However, the M1a1 can only shrug off HESH attacks from the front.  A 245m/s rock will have a much more pronounced arc than a tank shell which gives you a top-down hit to which tanks like the M1A1 do not have the advantage of thick spaced armor.

Won’t work
Your granite will shatter and scatter when it strikes the composite steel armour. That’s where almost all of the rock’s kinetic energy will go. You’ll scratch the paint on the tank and make it go ‘bong’ but not much beyond that.
If you accelerated the rock to supersonic speeds, maybe. But, the atmosphere would tear the rock apart before it reached the tank unless the range is absurdly short.

I think a rock going at relativistic speeds will definitely destroy a tank

@Coolcats112 Addresed

I don't think you can actually harm much a modern tank with a 500kg rock, even a hard one.
... but if you use your "device" to lift it about a kilometer meters above the tank and you're still able to hit it... perhaps your device could be useful to steer it on the way down.
A roughly spherical rock would be best.
